# Mobile-friendly design, something is blocking at 381px width

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I'm currently working on my project adding a mobile friendly design using CSS3 Media queries. I'm progressing fine, but I have a problem on the main page: When resizing the browser it gets stuck at 381px and doesn't go any tighter. My design should go all the way down to 240px in width.

It's the easiest to just give you the link to the page in question http://dev.hobbyathletes.com

There must be something in the container `<div class="content">` that blocks the resizing. I can't find it though. All the containers within have widths in percentage. There is a wowslider element in there, but I hide it with `display: none` at a width less than 480px

On http://dev.hobbyathletes.com/blogs it works fine, where the container `<div class="content">` is basically empty at the moment.

Your help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: more specificly the problem is in class `uc_rc_events` you need to check what's fixing the size of that

Comment: Yes you're right, the error seems to be somewhere in there...

Comment: Can't find anything... doesn't make sense to me... Any other idea?

Comment: okay, to be even more specific this class seems to be the problem: `.uc_rc_events li span[itemprop="name"]` if I do a display:none on this it resizes nicely all the way down to 240px

Comment: The issue was with the `white-space: nowrap` property in conjunction with percentage width. I added a new media query on max-width 390 and set `white-space:normal`. Not perfect, but working fine. PROBLEM SOLVED - Thanks!